# how to connect oracle cloud instances with guacamole using private key?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, guacamole

I have Guacamole server running on Ubuntu. Created connection for Digital Ocean droplet using SSH with password and works fine.

I have been trying to connect to Oracle cloud linux instances using Private Key. But when trying to connect it fails saying login failed. No idea what is going wrong.

Need some help to configure Guacamole connection to connect to Oracle cloud linux instance with private key. The private key provided by oracle while creation of instance.

Thanks.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

3 things need to aware:

1. private key format must be RSA, 2048bit, PEM (Putty>import PPK file > conversion > export openSSH key > save to *.PEM file)
2. Import to Private key field, the header is start from this string (”——-******BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY—-******”)
3. Edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the target server and add these two lines to the config. Then reboot sshd by sudo systemctl restart sshd

`HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`

`PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa`